# Convert/format a column in a SQL Server 2005 select statement 

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, formatting

I have an SQL query which is `select DateOfBirth from people`, and it shows up in the result pane as

```
DateOfBirth
07/07/2010 5:08:02
07/09/2010 5:08:02
07/13/2010 5:08:02
```

I want to format as,

```
07/Jul/2010 
09/Jul/2010
13/Jul/2010
```

**NOTE:** `DateOfBirth` column has datatype `nvarchar(50)`, not datetime...

Comment: @marc_s perhaps to support field-level encryption for this field (implemented at an application level) being configurably on or off. Or maybe to capture partially known DOBs (eg "I know his birthday was in December... and he turned 80 last year...").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little tricky as the best way to do this is to take the varchar convert it into a datetime and then format it. Annother complication is that the format you want is not a format that SQLServer will output.

So.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DateTime, DateOfBirth) from people
```

will get you the date time and we can then convert it to a string format as follows

```
SELECT CONVERT(DateTime, DateOfBirth), 106) from people
```

this will produce the string output 'dd Mon YYYY'

then its just a matter of replacing the spaces with '/'

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DateTime, DateOfBirth), 106), ' ','/')  FROM people
```

will get you the format you want.

Comment: Your 2nd convert should be char(10), no?

Comment: Yes probably better if you do a char(10) rather than a VARCHAR